# PHP & MySql Checkboxes and Binary Numbers for different combinations

Tags: php, mysql, binary

I just started a new project in which the user manages various Classes (as in school) where each class takes place on different days of the week.

For example there is a Violin class that happens every Monday and Wednesday. But there are also classes that will take place on multiple days, like everyday but Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

So, my mysql table has the fields: id int, name varchar, daysOfWeek binary, teacherID int.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing at this point, so I decided to set daysOfWeek to binary, so that the management page has checkboxes when adding a new entry and lets you choose which days the class takes places on, so for every day of the week a different binary number is generated.

So if I choose only monday it gives me 01000000 (or 64), for everyday except Saturday and Sunday it gives 01111100. With the first bit being Sunday and the last bit being ignored as we only have 7 days in a week.

This is the most pratical way I could come up to store these values.

My question is: Am I doing this wrong? Is there any other easy way to do this? Should I created a boolean field for each day on the week in my table?

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is a database deisgn issue not php/mysql.

But anyways.... why are you afraid to have more columns? One for each day. The columns could actually hold more info... for example the actual time of the lesson on that day, or the teacher, or the length of the lesson. Then when you query you can see a NULL value means no lesson, and also allows you to  query afternoon lessons or whatever.

Don't worry too much about optimizing from the start. Build it with all the functionality you need and then later look at improving it. Only with experience can you foresee problems better/earlier.